# Options for recording the tasks done in a browser for UI Automation Test

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, codeception, laravel-dusk

Is there a tool that can record user interactions with DOM elements for usage in creating automated tests (I'm using [Codeception](https://codeception.com/) and [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/dusk) but any tool with roots in Selenium is fine). I'm looking for something to record a sequence and get back a list that might include:

- Browser navigate to `/contact`
- Focus input "#name"
- Enter text "Joe" in input `#name`
- Focus textarea `textarea[name=message]`
- Enter text "Hello world" in textarea `textarea[name=message]`
- Click element `input[type=submit]`
- Browser navigate to `/contact?thanks`

I see [GhostInspector](https://ghostinspector.com/) but that is tied directly into a cloud based company and I don't want that, I'd like some degree of control over what the plugin does and be able to record pages not on the public web.

I can see building a tool that recorded every action is non-trivial - mousemove events, focus, text selection, keyboard events, scroll events, etc. Ideally I can say "listen to every focus, click, and keyup event on an input or textarea or button or select or option" and also watch for url changes.

Does such a tool exist? Doesn't matter what browser stack it runs on really, just need the ability for a user, maybe a novice user, to go to a website, hit record, do some actions, and get back a list of what occurred.

---

The instantaneous downvotes that contend my question is "not about programming" prompt me to improve my question. I don't presume the nature of the tool - it might be programming methods? Ways to use the browser to listen for all events and log them in some manner? Might be a Chrome extension? Might be a framework? Might be a library? *I'm looking for the experience of programmers to help me with the programming task I'm trying to accomplish.*

Comment: Legacy Selenium IDE ~2.9.0 and Firefox ~50 should be able to record the actions. the new Selenium IDE does not support exporting the test cases last time I checked.

Comment: Playing with https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/katalon-automation-record/ seems to do a great deal of what I need. Still experimenting.

Comment: _"I'm looking for the experience of programmers to help me with the programming task I'm trying to accomplish."_ - unfortunately, asking for recommendations on tools or libraries is off topic on this site. You might want to ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the Chrome extension Laravel TestTools?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/laravel-testtools/ddieaepnbjhgcbddafciempnibnfnakl

Answer (score 4):

Katalon Recorder (Selenium IDE for FF55+)

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/katalon-automation-record/

Answer (score 3):

The straight answer to your question is: Yes there are a number of tools available that are on top of Selenium. I will briefly discuss the top ones that also support browser extensions

**1. [New Selenium ID(Open Source)](https://www.seleniumhq.org)-** Selenium is possibly the most popular open-source test automation framework for Web applications. The new Selenium IDE is designed to record your interactions with websites to help you generate and maintain site automation, tests, and remove the need to manually step through repetitive takes.

**Features:**

- Recording and playing back tests on Firefox and Chrome.
- Organizing tests into suites for easy management.
- Saving and loading scripts, for later playback.

Selenium has become a core framework for other open-source test automation tools such as Katalon Studio, Watir, Protractor, and Robot Framework.

- [FireFox Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/)
- [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd?hl=en)

**2. [Kantu(Open-source)](https://a9t9.com/kantu)-** It is a record & replay tool for automated testing, web automation, automating file uploads and autofill form filling. The visual UI testing commands of Kantu help web designers and developers to verify and validate the layout of websites (and canvas elements).

**Features:**

- Kantu provides with built-in flow control commands like if/else/endif, while/endWhile or GotoIf
- [FireFox Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/kantu/)
- [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kantu-browser-automation/gcbalfbdmfieckjlnblleoemohcganoc)

**3. [Katalon Automation Recorder](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/katalon-automation-recorder/)-** Katalon have **Katalon Studio** which is a completely free desktop application. Recently they launched new Selenium IDE that helps you record actions, capture web elements on web applications, play automated test cases, and do reporting quickly and easily.***This Extension was the champion project of Katalon Studio Hackathons contest.***

**Features:**

- Record, play, debug with speed control, pause/resume, breakpoints capabilities.
- Enjoy fastest execution speed compared to other extensions with Selenium 3 core engine.
- Import test data from CSV files for data-driven testing.
- Report easily with logs, screenshots capturing, with historical data and analytics from Katalon Analytics.
- [FireFox Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/katalon-automation-record/)
- [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder-selenium/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

**Few references for further comparison:**

1. https://medium.com/@briananderson2209/best-automation-testing-tools-for-2018-top-10-reviews-8a4a19f664d2 (comments section will also helpful)
2. https://a9t9.com/blog/selenium-ide-2018/
3. https://www.g2crowd.com/categories/test-automation
4. https://www.qasymphony.com/blog/100-plus-best-software-testing-tools/

Comment: Link to download Selenium IDE - is this the best link? https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/ ?

Comment: downvoter,please give some comments.I think  that will be helpfull

Comment: @artlung-I added links in my answer